# Azure Cognitive Search - documents count less than indexed ones

Tags: azure, search

After creating an Azure Sql datasource and an indexer and related index, I run the indexer and it seeds successfully 18000 documents.
When I query the index with $count=true only 2036 documents are returned.
What could be the reason? I tried deleting index/indexer and dataspurce and recreating and still have the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a high chance you have duplicated documents or you're using the same key for those documents, which means those 2036 are unique documents.